# LINQ find more than 3 times in a row from string

Tags: linq

```
string x = "abcdeffffaaaasdfhfgjhfghzxxxx";
```

How do I get the character from the string if certain letter appears more than certain amount of time in a row, etc if any letter happens more than 3 times in a row, u will get 4 element of 'a' in a collection. Is it possible to use LINQ?

Comment: LINQ is itself not the answer. A regex would allow finding repeated characters (something like `"([a-z]{3,})"` applied for multiple matches). LINQ might be useful in extracting information from the `Match` instance.

Comment: Linq doesn't really support this, your much better of writing a loop manually.

Comment: @Richard the question is much simpler than the problem I'm facing, it is a list of object.

Comment: @Inhumane then provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for RegEx, but if you really want to use LINQ, i'd group your sequence of characters into groups of same characters, and count the number of elements in each group.

TODO: decide whether A a à À Ã ä are the same "letter" or different "letters". Use `StringCompare.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` and the like to overcome this problem

```
var CharacterCounts = sourceString       // get your source string as sequence of char
    .GroupBy(letter => letter           // group them into groups with same letter
    .Select(group => new                // from every group count the number of elements
    {
        Char = group.Key,
        Count = group.Count(),
    }
```

To know if any letter appears more than certain number:

```
bool someLettersOften = characterCounts
     .Where(characterCount => characterCount.Count > 3)
     .Any();
```

To get all letters that appear quite often:

```
 var oftenUsedLetters = characterCounts
     .Where(characterCount => characterCount.Count > 3)
     .Select(characterCount => characterCount.Character);
```

Comment: it has to be appear more than certain amount of time in a row, which mean consecutive